# Getting current transaction reference of JpaTransactionManager

Tags: spring, jpa-2.0, spring-transactions

We have started transaction in our service layer with @Transactional (org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional). We need to get current transaction reference in data access layer? Is there any way we can get reference of current transaction?

Below is the transaction configuration in our case:

**JPA Configuration**

```
<bean id="entityManagerFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean"
    p:persistenceUnitName="pUnitName"
    p:persistenceXmlLocation="classpath*:persistence.xml"
    p:dataSource-ref="dataSource" p:jpaVendorAdapter-ref="jpaAdapter">
    <property name="loadTimeWeaver">
        <bean
            class="org.springframework.instrument.classloading.InstrumentationLoadTimeWeaver" />
    </property>
</bean>
<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager"
    p:entityManagerFactory-ref="entityManagerFactory" />
<bean id="jpaAdapter"
    class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter"
    p:database="ORACLE" p:showSql="true" />
```

Comment: Why do yuo need the current transaction? What is your usecase...

Comment: I ask because in general it it a bad idea to mess around with the transaction directly when using declarative transaction management.

Comment: We need to track all database changes in a given transaction. Hence, I need to log kind of transaction id in entities for changes made in a specific transaction. I am wondering if I can get current transaction id (not sure whether any way to get generated id specific to a transaction) and log all the database changes with this id. Later on I can gather all the changes which are made in a transaction.

Comment: And which Id do you want to get? The transaction object from spring doesn't have one. Why not simply generate and id (using `UUID` for instance and store that). Next to that I would suggest using something like Hibernate Envers to track all the changes (and add some features to that instead of trying to invent your own).

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. If you don't mind, could you please provide more detail about 'Hibernate Envers to track all the changes' for this use case?

Comment: [Envers](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.2/devguide/en-US/html/ch15.html) is the default hibernate add-on for tracking changes in entities. For a recent version of hibernate the only thing to do is include the Hibernate Envers artifact, add `@Auditable` to your entities you want to track, and you are done. Now if you want to add some custom fields next to the default `revision` and `timestamp` you need to [extend Envers](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.2/devguide/en-US/html/ch15.html#envers-revisionlog) a little.

Comment: Thats a good option to track the changes. But in my application, I am tracking changes using Database triggers for audit purpose. That means before changing any row I am capturing old values and new values in different audit table. My requirement is just to have Id in each table to track the changes which are made for a specific transaction. If I will go for 'Hibernate Envers', I will have to change my path.

Comment: That you didn't mention :). You probably want to solve it on the database side then and do everything inside the triggers. That would be easier and more robust then a java/trigger solution. I can imagine oracle has support for certain triggers/procedures when a transaction starts.

Comment: Oops! I should have mentioned it before. Yeah, that can be one idea to get any transaction id during trigger (which are called before update/delete to capture old values) execution in oracle side itself. If I make any changes through UI, before changing any thing in database , triggers are executed, old data is captured, get the transaction id, save the old data, new data and transaction id in audit table and then finally save all changes to actual tables. This can be the flow in my case. Can't it?

Comment: I assume you have a trigger which basically saves the old (and maybe new) values to an audit/history table. You want to extend that with a transaction-id. This [thread](https://forums.oracle.com/thread/2188027?start=0&tstart=0) explains how to get the current transaction-id in Oracle, if you can retrieve that you can quit easily modify your triggers to store that with your audit information.

Comment: I have separate triggers for different tables. For example I have User and Address table and I have written two triggers say User_Change_Trigger and Address_Change_Trigger. And if I change user name and address in a single transaction my both triggers will be fired. While getting transaction id from triggers, I must get single transaction id from both triggers in this case. Since, triggers are executed separately, they will give different transaction id. Won't they?

Comment: No...Not as long as they are part of the a single transaction, they should also get the same transaction id. At least that is the theory.

Comment: If it will be then it will solve my problem. I will test it and revert back you.

Comment: Hurrey! I got this working. Oracle triggers those are executed in a single transaction, they also get the same transaction id. I get  transaction id using 'dbms_transaction.local_transaction_id'. In this way, I don't need to track transaction identifier in application side. This will be taken care in database itself for audit purpose. I appreciate M. Deinum for your responses. Thanks a lot.